# How do I get my function to return a result

Tags: javascript

I am trying to teach myself javascript but I not getting very far, I cant figure what I am doing wrong. I've created a function ,fixedSpending(),that takes two inputs num1 and num2 and adds them. I want the function to return the total when the user hits the "=" button. So far this is not happening, im  getting an uncaught reference error on the console because fixedSpending() is not defined but I dont understand why.

Any help or learning material would be appreciated.

```html
 <html>
    
    <head>
      <title>
        Budget Form
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function fixedSpending(){
          var num1=parseFloat(document.getElementById("num1").value)
          var num2=parseFloat(document.getElementById("num2").value)
    
          return document.getElementById('result').value= num1 + num2;
        } 
        </script>
      </title>
    
    </head>
    <body>
      <h2></h2>
      <br>
      num1:&nbsp;<input type="text" id="num1" maxlength="10"><br>
      num2:&nbsp;<input type="text" id="num2" maxlength="10"><br>
      <input type="Button" value= "=" onclick="fixedSpending();"><br>
      Result: <input type="text" id="result">
    </body>
</html>
```

Uncaught ReferenceError: fixedSpending is not defined

Comment: Works for me, but you shouldn't be returning an expression at the end of your function (no need to return anything).

Comment: Move your `<script>` tag outside of the `<title>` tag.

Comment: Rewrote it a bit: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/juya1opt/

Comment: Aahhh it works, thank you everyone! I didn't think the bad html would affect the javascript!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your HTML seems to be malformed, as you have your `<script>` tag inside your `<title>` tag. Your code should work if you just move it outside of the tag like so:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Budget Form</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function fixedSpending(){
            var num1=parseFloat(document.getElementById("num1").value)
            var num2=parseFloat(document.getElementById("num2").value)

            return document.getElementById('result').value= num1 + num2;
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2></h2>
        <br>
        num1:&nbsp;<input type="text" id="num1" maxlength="10"><br>
        num2:&nbsp;<input type="text" id="num2" maxlength="10"><br>
        <input type="Button" value= "=" onclick="fixedSpending();"><br>
        Result: <input type="text" id="result">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, pull the script out of your title tag, right now it's nested into it.

Second - Move the script down to just above the closing body tag (this one ). This is to ensure that the form fields you're trying to manipulate and use data from have rendered prior to doing anything with them, and is common practice.

Third - Remove the word "return" from your function. This function doesn't need to explicitly return anything, as you're not using the return value for anything. You just want the function to set the value of the result field. So just remove the word "return" from that last line of your function.

Answer (score 1):

As @Bjarke noted, your script is not embedded correctly. You should put the script just above the closing `</body>` tag. And you do not have to use `return` statement, since you are just assigning a value to an input field. Try:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Budget Form
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2></h2>
    <br>
    num1:&nbsp;<input type="text" id="num1" maxlength="10"><br>
    num2:&nbsp;<input type="text" id="num2" maxlength="10"><br>
    <input type="button" value= "=" onclick="fixedSpending();"><br>
    Result: <input type="text" id="result">
    <script>
        function fixedSpending() {
            var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num1").value)
            var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num2").value)
            document.getElementById('result').value = num1 + num2;
        };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Test this code on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mzvnfow2/2/